# Server click executes before user click on confirmation dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I work with ASP.NET

I have some button "Delete" which remove users.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDeleteUser" runat="server" OnClientClick="return ValidateDeleteUser();" OnClick="lnkDeleteUser_Click" CssClass=" btn btn-primary" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
```

My ValidateDeleteUser-function looks like :

```
    function ValidateDeleteUser() {

    if ($("#hdnNewUserFlag").val() != "Update") {
        Dialogs.Alert("Please select user", null, null);
        return false;
    }

    function okCallBack() {
        return true;
    }

    function cancelCallBack() {
        return false;
    }

    if ($("#hdnNewUserFlag").val() == "Update") {
        Dialogs.Confirmation("Are you sure you want to Delete this User?", okCallBack, cancelCallBack, null);
    }
}
```

where `Dialogs.Confirmation` - is my custom confirm-dialog.

```
    var Dialogs = new function() {
    var todo = null;

    function getConfirmModalDialog(title, textBody) {
        // create layout of dialog
        return dialog;
    };

    function getConfirmationtDialog(title, msg, okCallBack, cancelCallBack, callBackObj) {
        var ConfirmationDialog = $('#confirm-dialog');
        if (ConfirmationDialog.length == 0) {
            ConfirmationDialog = getConfirmModalDialog(title, msg);
        } else {
            $('.modal-title', ConfirmationDialog).html(title);
            $('.modal-body', ConfirmationDialog).html(msg);
        }

        $('.ok-btn', ConfirmationDialog).unbind('click').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (typeof okCallBack === "function") {
                todo = okCallBack(callBackObj);
            }
            ConfirmationDialog.modal('hide');
        });

        $('.cancel-btn', ConfirmationDialog).unbind('click').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (typeof cancelCallBack === "function") {
                todo = cancelCallBack(callBackObj);
            }
            ConfirmationDialog.modal('hide');
        });

        return ConfirmationDialog;
    };

    this.Confirmation = function (dialogMsg, okCallBack, cancelCallBack, callBackObj) {
        var dlg = getConfirmationtDialog('Confirmation', dialogMsg, okCallBack, cancelCallBack, callBackObj);
        dlg.modal('show');
    };
}
```

My problem is next : when user clicks on "Delete" Button, confirmation dialog opens and after this server side click executes, before user clicks on confirm-Ok-button.

Comment: i don't see a `return false`. Is that why the postback is happening?

Comment: @naveen, do you mean `return false;` on cancel-click? or in `ValidateDeleteUser` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that what you want to do is make the confirm button on the dialouge dot he postback to the server and not have the link button do the postback to the server.

Comment: something like what you said

Comment: well, i chose your answer, as i used ajax to make postback

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not using a `return false` like this.

```
if ($("#hdnNewUserFlag").val() == "Update") {
    Dialogs.Confirmation("Are you sure you want to Delete this User?", okCallBack, cancelCallBack, null);
    return false;
}
```

On calling `Dialogs.Confirmation`, the modal gets opened and the buttons get `click`. But nowhere are you telling your function to *wait* for the click event. So after executing the JavaScript code, the server-side event will be executed.

Update: You should be returning false to the main function which calls `Dialogs.Confirm`. That is, `ValidateDeleteUser` as done above. Otherwise the main function will `return true`

Comment: in second case, nothing happens after confirm-dialog opens, but after ok-button-click also nothing happens (server side click doesn't run)

Comment: because you are giving `e.preventDefault();` remove it and place `return true` at the end of the code

Comment: well, yes, this make sense. But i get error : when i init `todo` variable with `okCallBack`, value of `todo` is bool, howeever i expect function. I call `todo` on modal hide event